# How to delete an ndb.model after querying it?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am having the following code to delete an entity: (I am using Python in Google App Engine)

```
id = request.POST.get('id')
user = ndb.Key(urlsafe=id).get()
user.key.delete()
```

But it is not getting deleted. Please help.

Comment: Is the id from the post a `key.urlsafe()` string?

Comment: yes. Id from the post is a `key.urlsafe()` string.

Comment: how do you know that is not deleted?

Comment: If you perform a query that for that entity, it may still be found for a period as a result of Eventual Consistency. If you performa a get() with the key after you have deleted the entity, then yes it's really not being deleted, however I doubt that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks at least possible that you're just observing "eventual consistency" but somehow expecting "strong consistency".  To check, you could for example do

```
checking = user.key.get()
assert checking is None
```

after your `user.key.delete()` to verify that it worked.

`get` on a `Key` is strongly consistent, so the `assert` should work properly.

Note that, in general, `get` on a **query** is only **eventually** consistent -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6EaoPMANQM&t=1m15s -- so if that's what you're using to check, it may be misleading you.  (If you do need strong consistency on queries, you need to give all entities involved a common ancestor, and make an ancestor query).